# Android admob doesn't work for version 2.3.3 video ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

Currently I have implemented an video advertise in my project.I am using [admob adapter](http://developer.brightroll.com/admob/)for this.

The demo works fine for 4.2.1 but it crashes for 2.3.5.
Log is as follows:

```
01-28 11:03:23.433: D/Database(23886): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.brightroll.brightrollintegrationexample/databases/webview.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno: 2,message: No such file or directory
01-28 11:03:23.433: D/Database(23886): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.brightroll.brightrollintegrationexample/databases/webview.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 21 M, handle: 0x252860
01-28 11:03:23.923: V/webviewdatabase(23886): TCP pre connection: creating table in database
01-28 11:03:24.034: D/Database(23886): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.brightroll.brightrollintegrationexample/databases/webviewCache.db, flag = 6, cannot stat file, errno: 2,message: No such file or directory
01-28 11:03:24.044: D/Database(23886): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.brightroll.brightrollintegrationexample/databases/webviewCache.db, mode: delete, disk free size: 21 M, handle: 0x24dcf8
01-28 11:03:24.354: D/skia(23886): htcFlashPlugin::htcFlashPlugin
01-28 11:03:24.354: D/qct(23886): [WebView.WebView] >> Enable Shutdown = true
01-28 11:03:24.364: D/WindowManagerImpl(23886): addView, new view, mViews[0]: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4069dcb0
01-28 11:03:24.454: D/qct(23886): [RequestQueue.ActivePool.ActivePool] >> Enable Shutdown = true
01-28 11:03:24.454: D/qct(23886): [IdleCache.IdleCache] >> IDLE_CACHE_MAX = 40
01-28 11:03:24.764: D/webkit-timers(23886): [JWebCoreJavaBridge::resume] >> do resume
01-28 11:03:25.605: D/dalvikvm(23886): GC_CONCURRENT freed 195K, 40% free 3399K/5639K, external 0K/0K, paused 10ms+5ms
01-28 11:03:25.675: W/dalvikvm(23886): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
01-28 11:03:25.675: W/dalvikvm(23886): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
01-28 11:03:25.675: W/dalvikvm(23886):   502: 0x401938b8 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Ljava/lang/String;' (284 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.675: W/dalvikvm(23886):   503: 0x40696788 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.675: W/dalvikvm(23886):   504: 0x406e5600 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   505: 0x401938b8 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Ljava/lang/String;' (284 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   506: 0x40696788 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   507: 0x406e5698 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   508: 0x401938b8 cls=Ljava/lang/Class; 'Ljava/lang/String;' (284 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   509: 0x40696788 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   510: 0x406e5720 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   511: 0x4071e338 cls=Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; (36 bytes)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   169 of Ljava/lang/Class; 284B (1 unique)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):     1 of Ljava/lang/Class; 9332B
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):     1 of Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; 36B
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):     1 of [Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; 1548B
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):   339 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (171 unique)
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886):     1 of Lcom/brightroll/androidsdk/RTB; 124B
01-28 11:03:25.685: W/dalvikvm(23886): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 16112 bytes
01-28 11:03:25.695: E/dalvikvm(23886): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
01-28 11:03:25.695: I/dalvikvm(23886): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 RUNNABLE
01-28 11:03:25.695: I/dalvikvm(23886):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x406b1268 self=0x24eef0
01-28 11:03:25.695: I/dalvikvm(23886):   | sysTid=23901 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2420776
01-28 11:03:25.695: I/dalvikvm(23886):   | schedstat=( 617278346 715788246 1845 )
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(Native Method)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.loadUrl(BrowserFrame.java:332)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.loadUrl(WebViewCore.java:1938)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$1900(WebViewCore.java:74)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1079)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:696)
01-28 11:03:25.705: I/dalvikvm(23886):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
01-28 11:03:25.705: E/dalvikvm(23886): VM aborting
```

Is there any special thing needed ?

```
 android:minSdkVersion="8"
 android:targetSdkVersion="15"
```

Please do suggest any solution.